# How to find out which device is taking the bandwidth, inside a home's WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth, wifi-configuration

Almost all houses have WiFi, and its people connect to it via different devices. Laptop, PC, smartphones, even IoT solutions coming.

I have a very basic need. I want to know which device is devouring WiFi's bandwidth, because others feel terrible speed and connectivity.

Yet I can't find a software to do that. I mean, I'm not a network professional, but this seems to be a very very widespread need. The first step in finding out why Internet connection is slow, is to find out what's consuming it. Am I right?

Do we have an application that makes it easy to find out connected devices and their usage and traffic?

Comment: what about using etherape or wireshark to monitor network bandwith

Comment: Rereading your post, I wonder if the issue is that the WIFI bandwidth is being devoured by one of the devices or if the problem is congestion on the WIFI bands. First thing I would do is look at the WIFI signals in the area using something like WIFI analyser on Android.  Alternatively test the hypothesis by looking at latencies between LAN clients - if these are high & variable then  your problem is most likely wifi interence/noise - unless you have an Internet connection faster then your WIFI one.

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is wrong (ie this is not a very basic need), which means that this is info is surprisingly hard to get.   Most home user grade routers do not have a way of getting it.

If you have a router which supports DD-WRT or similar you can flash your router with this software and then use a software adon for it to monitor data per IP - possibly [YAMon](http://usage-monitoring.com/index.php)

Comment: I totally disagree. This is the problem of scarcity. If someone eat all the food, then others starve to death. If son of one-car family take the car out, then other family members should wait for him to come back. The entire economy as a science is based on the notion of **scarcity**. So, it's definitely a common need. Not just in a house, everywhere that people share a scarce resource there should be some mechanism to measure the usage of each member.

Comment: Your tangent about scarcity may be correct, however a "common need" is not a "very basic need" - if it were a "very basic need", basic routers would have this functionality built in - which they don't - and that was my point.

Comment: I understood your point, thank you for clarification. Yeah, it's not a **basic need**. Not all common things are basic.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer will seem pretty far off from what you were asking for, but please bear with me. **The first possibility you need to eliminate is bufferbloat.** I'll explain.

In most households, the Wi-Fi isn't used for LAN-to-LAN traffic much, it's mostly used for Internet traffic. So when people say their home Wi-Fi gets slow when a lot of people are using it, they really mean that their ability to access stuff on the Internet gets slow when a lot of people are using it.

The likely congestion point in a typical household's Internet traffic is not your Wi-Fi airtime, it's more likely to be your broadband link. Some people have the mistaken notion that when a network link gets congested, increased latency (lag, ping round trip times, etc.) is a natural result. But that's not true. If latency spikes up when your link is congested, it's a sign that one or more pieces of your networking equipment (modems/gateways/routers/APs) has a well-known bug called **bufferbloat**.

Bufferbloat is when your network equipment deals with congestion by just buffering everything and letting the backlog of buffered packets get longer and longer and longer without ever dropping any packets. Old time routers didn't do this. RAM was more expensive in the early days of the Internet, so routers didn't have enough RAM to buffer lots of packets, so they would quickly run out of buffer space and start dropping packets when congestion happened. TCP's Congestion Control algorithms would detect dropped packets and use that as trigger for the congestion control algorithms to kick in. But now RAM is cheap and modern routers can buffer tons of packets, and in doing so, they accidentally hide the fact that congestion is occurring, so TCP congestion control never kicks in. All that these bloated buffer queues do is add ever-increasing latency to the network, making the network feel very slow.

So, whenever people feel like their home network is slow, the first thing they need to do is run a tool like [dslreports.com/speedtest](http://dslreports.com/speedtest) which provides a bufferbloat latency grade. Run it at a time when you notice that your network is being slow. If you get a bad bufferbloat grade, then address your bufferbloat problem first, before bothering to try to accuse one user, device, or process of hogging the bandwidth. Using QoS (or lecturing family members) to punish high-bandwidth traffic flows is usually NOT necessary. Fix bufferbloat first.

One way to address bufferbloat is to enable a bufferbloat-aware "Smart Queue Management" (SQM) algorithm such as FQ-CoDel on your router at the head of your network. If you router can run any well-known aftermarket open source Linux-based router firmware distro such as LEDE, OpenWrt, or DD-WRT, you can follow the instructions online for how to do this. Those instructions will also tell you about adjusting the traffic-shaping capabilities of your router to make your router a slight bottleneck on your network. By making your bufferbloat-savvy router a slight bottleneck, it will allow TCP congestion control to kick in before bufferbloat can happen on any other box on your network.

If you don't want to fiddle with aftermarket firmware distros, you can buy turn-key bufferbloat-savvy router solutions such as evenroute.com's IQrouter. I haven't used it myself, so I can't vouch for it, but they specifically market it as taking care of bufferbloat in the way I've described above.

**IF it turns out that you really don't have a bufferbloat problem** and something else is really happing on your network, my best tip for you is to remember that the scarce resource on Wi-Fi is **airtime**, not bandwidth. Depending on the flavor of Wi-Fi your AP and client devices support, and how far a given client is from the AP, some Wi-Fi devices on your network could be using airtime up to 1733 times more efficiently than other devices. So a state-of-the-art device could be sending a gigabit per second of traffic and still use less airtime than an older device, farther away from the AP, that's stuck using the old 1Mbps data rate. So if you look at bandwidth instead of airtime, you'd be tempted to punish the gigabit-per-second guy, when actually the 1Mbps guy is the one using up an unreasonable amount of airtime. So always remember to divide a given device's bandwidth usage by it average PHY rate to get the airtime, and compare airtime usage, not bandwidth between devices.

Comment: Damn, I was searching for a simple recipe, and here is a university-grade lecture. +1 for all the good things that you taught me. But I'm gonna say no to this. Cause it's way more complicated than my slowness. I'll wait till speed gets up again. Thank you.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati At least run the dslreports tool I linked to, to see your bufferbloat grade the next time the network is slow. If you get a bad grade, you'll know not to bother trying to find a bandwidth hog until you've addressed your bufferbloat problem.